# WSO2 Identity Server multiple callback URLs breaks checksession endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm having an issue configuring multiple callback urls for a Service Provider in WSO2 Identity Server. This process is necessary for my team to support SLO (Single Logout) with a post logout redirect url.

## Callback URL Configuration

The WSO2 online documentation describes the correct way to do this process [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/OpenID+Connect+Logout+URL+Redirection). I have followed those step and configured my Callback URL as follows:

`regexp=(http://localhost:8080/login-callback|http://localhost:8080/logout-callback)`

This process works, and I am able to configure the two Callback URLs.

## Unintended "checksession" Side Effect

Once the callback urls are configured, the checksession endpoint stops working. The error message I get from the endpoint says "Invalid OP IFrame Request". That checksession call uses a url like this: `https://<wso2host>/oidc/checksession?client_id=<clientid>`

I verified that the checksession endpoint works if I configure either of my redirect urls individually

- http://localhost:8080/login-callback
- http://localhost:8080/logout-callback

But fails if I use the regexp syntax. Failure occurs in each of these scenarios:

- regexp=(http://localhost:8080/login-callback|http://localhost:8080/logout-callback)
- regexp=(http://localhost:8080/login-callback)
- regexp=(http://localhost:8080/logout-callback)

Am I missing a configuration step needed for either the callback urls or the checksession endpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution from a hint in the WSO2 logs.

When multiple callback urls are defined, the request for the checksession endpoint must specifiy a callback url as well. The correct checksession reqeust for my scenario was:

`https://<wso2host>/oidc/checksession?client_id=<clientid>&redirect_uri=<redirecturi>`